# Change CiviCRM extension (module) names

Tags: civicase

I want to change the Case extension/module name from Case to Tasks in CiviCRM and not sure if it is possible. Having worked with SuiteCRM, I know this can be done but not sure where in Civi this is/can done?

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use [word replacements](https://www.cividesk.com/blog/did-you-know-any-word-or-phrase-civicrm-can-be-replaced-another-one) in Civi?

Comment: Thank you Pradeep!